# Ordering References in a has_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

I am planning out my Database Schema for a rails app and part of it involved build a dynamic curriculum of sorts. The Schema would look a bit like this:

[image: Schema Diagram]

My problem is, while I want Problems and Snippets to be their own model, I want each lesson to have it's own ordering for the problems and snippets. As in two different lessons might share some of the same problems and snippets but in a different order.

What's the best method to do this in rails? I was envisioning that lessons could hold on to an array of id's to keep track of order but that doesn't seem very conventional.

Is there a standard for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need an intermediate table with a `has_many: through` relation between lesson and problem, also between lesson and snippets.

Comment: @Emu Could you elaborate on how that would work or share a link? Thanks!

Comment: @Emu Oh now that I'm thinking about it, that makes sense, I forgot that what I was doing was creating a Many-to-Many relationship. If you'd like to create an answer, I'll gladly mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediate table with a `has_many: through` relation between lesson and problem, also between lesson and snippets.

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lesson_problems, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :problems, through: :lesson_problems
end

class Problem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lesson_problems, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lessons, through: :lesson_problems
end

class LessonProblem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :problems
  belongs_to :lessons
end
```

In lesson_problems table there will be an extra column named `order`. 
Same goes for Lesson and Snippet. 
Detail can be found [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)